# How to check if list of phrases exists in the text?

Tags: string, list, text, f#

I have been trying to create a filter that checks if a phrase in a list of phrases exists in the text using recursive functions and match patterns, but somehow that does not seems to work... Maybe someone could give me hint why?

```
let rec matchTails (tail1 : string list) (tail2 : string list) = 
    match tail1, tail2 with
        | h1::t1 , h2::t2 -> 
            if (h1=h2) then 
                matchTails t1 t2
            else
                false
        | _, [] -> false
        | [],_-> true

let rec check2 (textH: string) (textT: string list) (phrases: string list list) = 
    match phrases with 
    |[] -> ()
    | h :: t ->
        printfn "%s -- %s" (h.Head) (textH)
        match h with
        |x when x.Length = 1 && x.Head = textH -> 
            ()
        |x when x.Head = textH && (matchTails (textT) (x)) ->
            printfn "%s" (x.Head)
        | _ -> ()
        check2 (textH) (textT) (t)

let rec check (phrases : string list list) (text:string list) = 
    match text with
    | [] -> ()
    | h :: t ->
        check2 (h) (t) (phrases)
        check phrases t


let p = [["rolex"]; ["free"; "spins"; "everyday"]; ["free"; "cash"]]

let t = ["hello";"and";"welcome";"to";"our";"annual";"free";"cash";"and";"rolex";"giveaway"]
```

Function call: check p t

I have edited my question with fixing few mistakes, but however, with these lists the program is giving unit() as an output...

Comment: You've got `h2 = h2` in your match expression. This will always evaluate to true. Did you mean `h1 = h2` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are some hints:

- `matchTails` returns incorrect result for

  ```
  matchTails [ "asdf1" ] [ "asdf" ] => true
  matchTails [ "asdf" ] [ "asdf"; "asdf1" ] => true
  matchTails [ ] [ "" ] => true
  ```

  I suspect it should return `false` in all these cases. Probably the implementation you want is:

  ```
  let rec matchTails (phrase : string list) (text : string list) = 
    match phrase, text with
    | h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2 -> if h1 = h2 then matchTails t1 t2
                            else false
    | [ ], _ -> true
    | _ -> false

  let matchTails_test () =
    if not (matchTails [ "" ] [ "" ]) then raise Exception()
    ...
  ```
- `check2` is not called recursively so only the first phrase is checked
- `check` is not called recursively, it calls check2 and returns

Generally, try to decompose problem into smaller functions and test each of them separately. You are moving in right direction, what is missing is clarity of what the each of the functions should do and test cases.

Update:

Note that `check2` does not really return any value (it returns unit). Also it functionality overlaps with `matchTails` - it checks the head with the first word in the phrase, it is what `matchTails` does anyway.

`check` also returns unit, () means unit.

So let's rewrite `check`:

```
let rec check (phrases : string list list) (text : string list) =
  if phrases |> List.exists (fun ph -> matchTails ph text) then
    true
  else
    match text with
    | [] -> false
    | _ :: tail -> check phrases tail
```

Comment: I have edited my question, and fix those mistakes, but the program seems to find the phrase with the length of 1, but not the longer ones..

Answer (score 0):

While the question has now [been basically answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069524), I would like to point out that its division into sub-problems is already very sufficient; shockingly lacking are the associated testing, and some descriptive naming of the individual functions tackling each sub-problem.

What about naming (and testing) `matchTails`, `check2` and `check` exemplarily like this?

```
let ps = [["rolex"]; ["free"; "spins"; "everyday"]; ["free"; "cash"]]
let t = ["hello";"and";"welcome";"to";"our";"annual";"free";"cash";"and";"rolex";"giveaway"]

startsWithPhrase ["hello"; "and"] t
containsPhrase ["free"; "cash"] t
containsAnyPhrase ps t
```

Spoiler:

> ```
> let rec startsWithPhrase phrase text = 
>     match phrase, text with
>     | h1::t1, h2::t2 when h1 = h2 -> startsWithPhrase t1 t2
>     | [], _-> true
>     | _ -> false
>
> let rec containsPhrase phrase text =
>     startsWithPhrase phrase text ||
>     match text with
>     | _::tl -> containsPhrase phrase tl
>     | [] -> false
>
> let rec containsAnyPhrase phrases text =
>     match phrases with
>     | h::tl -> 
>         containsPhrase h text ||
>         containsAnyPhrase tl text
>     | [] -> false
> ```

---

It may be much easier to stay completely with high-level functions, each in place of one recursive loop. Albeit here with a slighty different approach, dividing your haystack into needle-sized slices and comparing each of them with a given phrase.

```
let containsPhraseHL phrase text = 
    Seq.windowed (List.length phrase) text
    |> Seq.exists (Seq.forall2 (=) phrase)

containsPhraseHL ["free"; "cash"] t

let containsAnyPhraseHL phrases text =
    List.exists (fun phrase -> containsPhraseHL phrase text) phrases

containsAnyPhraseHL ps t
```